# This class should be public (android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.HomeView)

Tags: android, class, public, android-support-library

I am trying to create a Android Application which uses 3 spinners. I keep getting this error and I can't figure out how to fix it. 
**This class should be public (android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.HomeView)**

Comment: Are you using Proguard?

Comment: no. proguard is disabled.

Comment: Hi.. i got same error. did you find any solutions?

Comment: hello. no luck :( intellij didn't give me this problem.

Comment: Same problem here to and can't find a solution

Answer (score 51, accepted):

On the "v7-appcompat" library:

preferences -> Android Lint Preferences

Search for "Instantiatable" and set to Warning.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using Eclipse:

```
Project > Clean > OK
```

Or Try:

```
Preferences -> Android Lint Preferences
```

Search for `Instantiatable` and set as `Warning`.

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html

This worked for me.

Comment: Yes!! This is the easiest solution for me. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Go to **appcompat_v7 library** -> `Properties` -> `Android Lint Preferences` -> `Instantiatable` -> Select "`Warning`" severity.

[image]

**[Android Lint Checks](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks)**

> **Instantiatable**
>   Summary: Ensures that classes registered in the manifest file are instantiatable
>
> Priority: 6 / 10 Severity: Warning Category: Correctness
>
> Activities, services, broadcast receivers etc. registered in the
>   manifest file must be "instiantable" by the system, which means that
>   the class must be public, it must have an empty public constructor,
>   and if it's an inner class, it must be a static inner class.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution, in the project.properties file, just replace the line saying

```
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7_3
```

with

```
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7
```

That solved the problem to me at least.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this manually in the build.gradle file:

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    disable "Instantiatable"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a true solution, but maybe help.

Create project with higher API level then 8.

Whenever I select minimum Required SDK to API level 9 instead 8 this error does not happen.

Observation: My last answer was deleted, maybe the moderator think it was barely more than a link to an external site, for this reason I don't posted the link again.

Comment: I am using minSdkVersion 11 and still it happens

Comment: this answer helped me solve my problem. for me, Increasing the minimum sdk to 14 solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

> Eclipse inside the setup issues.  Windows -> Preferences -> Android ->
>   Lint Error Checking 
>   -> Enter "Instantiatable" Inside the Issues -> select the Search Content -> lower right corner Severity election warning -> OK!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is pretty old. However, would like to add in the updated answer to resolve this issue.

```
android {
    .
    .
    .
    lintOptions {
        warning("Instantiatable")
    }
}
```

Add the above lines to your gradle file.
Basically what this does is, it tells the linter to treat Instantiatable rule as a warning and not error.