# Android Eclipse public class error

Tags: android, eclipse

I know this question has already been asked here [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314733/android-public-class-error) and here [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22821420/this-class-should-be-public-android-support-v7-internal-widget-actionbarview-ho) but neither have a proper solution so I'm hoping that someone may now know a solution as it's driving me insane.

I'm new to android app design using Eclipse and I created a simple "Hello World" app and wanted to test it but I can't because I'm getting the error:**`This class should be public (android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.HomeView)`**.

I never had this problem come up yesterday and today I haven't altered my code at all but the error pops up when I run `Lint Warnings`; stopping me from running the test emulator.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem at all or why it's suddenly appeared out of nowhere?

Comment: try cleaning the  project once and check

Comment: @Siva tried that, no good.

Comment: What API level are you using?

Comment: @Dimitri I think minimum API 9. I'm new to android dev so apologies if I'm incorrect

Answer (score 0):

This has been logged as a bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73265

If you've only created a hello world app, I'm a little unsure why you would need to pull in anything from the support libraries. The top answer on the second link should work (making sure lint flags it as a warning and not an error), but you could also make sure you set the target API level higher. I would suggest API 14 based on *current market share