# Android - why do I get this lint error: "This class should be public (android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.HomeView)"

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, lint

> This class should be public
>   (android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.HomeView)
>
> Issue: Ensures that classes registered in the manifest file are
>   instantiatable Id: Instantiatable
>
> Activities, services, broadcast receivers etc. registered in the
>   manifest file must be "instantiatable" by the system, which means that
>   the class must be public, it must have an empty public constructor,
>   and if it's an inner class, it must be a static inner class.

This lint error with the Support Library - which occurs when I try to export my (unobfuscated) Android project - is also described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22821420/this-class-should-be-public-android-support-v7-internal-widget-actionbarview-ho). But why does this error occur in the first place? (Is it a bug with the Support Library?)

The suggested advice in that question is to just disable/downgrade the lint message to a 'Warning', but is it perfectly safe/correct to do that (i.e., maybe that is papering over some cracks?) or is there a better solution?

Comment: were you able to find a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure. That was two years ago probably back in my Eclipse days. If you get really stuck, try gradually building your project up from scratch (gradually introducing dependencies and proguard settings, etc.) in Android Studio until you come across the issue. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: company uses Eclipse unfortunately so I've had to go in reverse from AS to Eclipse :(, thanks tho!